# PowerShell regex to filter particular section in a file

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0, regex-greedy

There is a file called "Content.asa" which has following line:

```
Session("DBName") = "xxxyyyzzz"
```

I want to write a regulax expression to filter this line. Here `xxxyyyzzz` means any number of letters or characters. It doesn't have to be `xxxyyyzzz` all the time. The value will change always. for example,

```
Session("DBName") = "Abcdxxxyyyzzz"
or
Session("DBName") = "databaseName"
or 
Session("DBName") = "dummyvalue"
```

Once I excute regex command, it shoud give me only that particular line as my output.

Can someone please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`'Session\("DBName"\)\s*=\s*"(.*?)"'`](https://regex101.com/r/CtSABn/1) ?

Comment: Thank you so much. This is working fine.

Comment: @wOxxOm you should post it as an answer :)

Comment: Will it be useful to anyone else? Previously such questions were closed/deleted(?) as overly specific.